# Matlab exception sent by mail is not showing the line of the error

Tags: matlab, exception

In my matlab script I am sending a mail to me with an exception that tells me, when an error happens, which kind of error it is.

The problem I am facing is the fact that the ME exception is not showing me where the error happens (which line and which part of the code) as matlab usually does. I can't see the error in the matlab terminal too (the program just stops running). The code that sends the mail with the error is below:

```
try
% my script which can fail....
demo
catch ME
% An error will put here.
errorMessage = sprintf('Error in demo. The error is: %s', ME.message);
%this function just sends the mail
sendmail2me(errorMessage);
```

What I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception `ME` is an MException object which contains an `identifier`, the `message`, a `cause` and the `stack`. The `identifier` is only there to allow MATLAB an unique identification of an error. The `message` contains a description of the error.

The `cause` contains an array of MExceptions which have led to the current exception. This allows you to track the exceptions to find the root of your error. As the `cause` is a (possibly empty) array of MException objects, you could go through the `cause` in an array and write the information into the mail.

Most important for you is the `stack`. It is a struct containing three fields: `file`, `name` and `line`. File is the full path to the file/function where the error occurred. Name is (obviously) the name of the file and in line (again obviously) the line where the exception occurred is saved. The `stack` can also be an array if the error occurred in a function called from you function/script. It would therefore be best to go through `stack` in a for loop, and concatenate the error message and the contents of the stack.

```
try
    demo;
catch ME
    errormsg = sprintf('%s\n',ME.message);
    for k=1:length(ME.stack)
        errormsg = sprintf('%s\nError in %s (line %d)\n', ...
                   errormsg,ME.stack(k).name,ME.stack(k).line);
    end
    sendmail2me(errormsg);
end
```

You find more detailed information on Exceptions in the MATLAB [help pages](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/capture-information-about-errors.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But how can I  concatenate the contents of ME.stack in a single string so I can send it by mail?

Comment: I added a code example which generates almost the same output as the error in the MATLAB console would. I hope this helps